# Java super method call in a subtype overridden method

Tags: java, super, overriding, subtyping

could someone please explain me why if i run this code the output is [4, 2]:null and not [4,2]: purple?
What I understand is that the problem sits in the toString method in the superClass. 
In fact if I remove the "final" from toString in SuperClass and write a toString method like

```
    public String toString() {
        return this.makeName();
    }
```

in the subClass all works fine.
But I don't really understand the concept behind that.
Does exists something to read about this?

Thank you for your time.

```
public class Point { 
    protected final int x, y;
    private final String name;

    public Point(int x, int y) { 
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        name = makeName();
    }
    protected String makeName() { 
        return "["+x+", "+y+"]";
    }
    public final String toString(){ 
        return name;
    } 
}
```

ColorPoint.java:

```
public class ColorPoint extends Point { 
    private final String color;

    public ColorPoint(int x,int y, String color) { 
        super(x, y);
        this.color = color;
    }
    protected String makeName() {
        return super.makeName() + ":" + color;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println(new ColorPoint(4, 2, "purple"));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do :

`super(x, y);`

it invokes the constructor of your super class and hence `makeName()` method (due to line `name = makeName();`).

Since you redefined it in your subclass it calls it but color isn't defined at this moment.

Hence `return super.makeName() + ":" + color;` is equivalent to `return super.makeName() + ":" + null;`

So the execution flow is equivalent in the following (simplified) :

```
new ColorPoint(4, 2, "purple") //<-- creating ColorPoint object
super(x, y); //<-- super call
this.x = 4; 
this.y = 2;
name = makeName(); //<-- call makeName() in your ColorPoint class
return super.makeName() + ":" + color; //<-- here color isn't defined yet so it's null
name = "[4, 2]:null";
color = "purple";
/***/
print [4, 2]:null in the console //you call the toString() method, since it returns name you get the following output
```

---

Note that you could really simplify your classes with the following :

```
class Point { 
    protected final int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) { 
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return "["+x+", "+y+"]";
    }
}

class ColorPoint extends Point { 
    private final String color;

    public ColorPoint(int x,int y, String color) { 
        super(x, y);
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + ":" + color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your toString() method returns the value of variable `name`. This variable is filled during the constructor of your superclass, by calling the overridden method `makeName()`.

At this time, the variable `color` of the subclass has not yet been filled, so it correctly returns `[4,2]:null`

Answer (score 0):

You call the super(int, int) before assigning the value to color, so makeName() is invoked before color has a value, therefore: null.